# access variable of a view controller from a pushed view controller

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a navigation view controller to handle two view controllers; one each for the landscape and portrait orientations.
Now, I need to set a propery belonging to the view controller A(for vertical) that pushed the view controller B (for horizontal), from the view controller B.
Is there any way I can achieve this?
Sample codes and examples are welcome :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from A to B:

Define a property on view controller B to house the variable. In the code where you create view controller B, before you push it, set the property to A's value.

To get from B to A:

when you create B, use `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` to add A as an observer of the property on B. Then when B changes, you get a change notification, and you can update the property on A. See [the KVO section here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html).

Comment: hey, thanks for the prompt reply :) I have done this for passing value from A to B...but my problem is actually the other way round: How do i set a property that belongs to A before I pop B,from B???

Comment: @Bangdel my bad, I misinterpreted your question. Updated.